# Combing multiple boolean operators in a search request

Tags: support, filtering, custom-questions-list

I'm trying to search all C++ question with score ranging from 10 up to 1000. I also wanted only to show unanswered questions, that are not marked as a duplicate.

But if I type:

```
[c++] score:10..1000 isanswered:false duplicate:false
```

I still have answered questions in my result list. What I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

`isanswered:false` doesn't count answers that have a score of less than 1 as answers, even if they're accepted.

Instead, filter by having 0 answers to exclude results with any answer independent of answer score:

```
score:10..1000 answers:0 [c++] duplicate:false
```